# Error when calculating subtotal

Tags: php, postgresql

I have some trouble with my auto subtotal with php.

When first subtotal only record second & next can auto subtotal but first record on first subtotal can not sum just haves subtotal self.

But for second & next subtotal summary is right, you can see picture below:

[image: Please see for Image result in here]

Please help me this my PHP code.

```
$rm_kode    = $_POST['wl'];
$tahun      = $_POST['th'];
$bulan      = $mLoad->add_zero($_POST['bl']);
#$m_db2->debug = true;

if(!empty($bulan)){
    if(!empty($rm_kode)){
        $tanya  = "AND kode_rsm='$rm_kode'";
    }

    $rs = $m_db2->Execute("SELECT DISTINCT
            nm_wil,
            kode_rsm,
            nama_rsm,
            area,
            area_am_kode,
            area_am_nama,
            mr_kode,
            mr_nama,
            tahun,
            bln,
            SUM (
                (
                    CASE
                    WHEN target_qty < 0 THEN
                        0
                    ELSE
                        target_qty
                    END
                )
            ) AS target_qty,
            SUM (
                (
                    CASE
                    WHEN target_value < 0 THEN
                        0
                    ELSE
                        target_value
                    END
                )
            ) AS target_value,
            SUM (total_qty) AS total_qty,
            SUM (total_value) AS total_value                                                        
        FROM
            v_report_sales_2015
        WHERE
            tahun= '$tahun'
        AND (
            bln= '$bulan'
            /*AND bln :: INTEGER <= '11'*/
        )
        --AND target_qty<>-1
        $tanya
        AND am_is_lock = 'f'
        AND rsm_is_lock = 'f'
        AND mr_is_lock = 'f'
        GROUP BY
            mr_kode,
            mr_nama,
            area,
            area_am_kode,
            area_am_nama,
            kode_rsm,
            nama_rsm,
            nm_wil,                                                     
            tahun,
            bln");

    $no =1; 

    #Get Nama SM
    $rsb    = $m_db2->Execute("SELECT usr_nama FROM vsiko_users WHERE usr_sales='$rm_kode'");

    #Set awal nilai sebagai nol;
    $sub_tqty   = $sub_tval = $sub_rqty = $sub_rval = $goal_am = 0;

    while(!$rs->EOF)
    {

        #Group By SM
        if($cur_rsm!=$rs->fields['kode_rsm'])
        {
            $cur_rsm    =$rs->fields['kode_rsm'];
            $am = 1;

            echo '<tr>
                    <td colspan="8"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="alert alert-warning">
                    <td></td>
                    <td>'.$rs->fields['kode_rsm'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$rs->fields['nama_rsm'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$rs->fields['nm_wil'].'</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                  </tr>';
        }

        #Group By AM                                
        if(@$cur_am!=$rs->fields['area_am_kode'])
        {
            $cur_am = $rs->fields['area_am_kode'];

            #Produk Group AM
            $rsc    = $m_db2->Execute("SELECT a.ins_group_produk FROM mst_insentive_pgroup AS a WHERE a.ins_kode='".$rs->fields['pg_am']."'");

            echo '<tr>
                    <td colspan="8"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="alert alert-success">
                    <td align="center">
                    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success" onclick=bukaWin("detail.mul?app=sales&mod=print_sales_am&th='.str_replace('=','',base64_encode($tahun)).'&bl='.str_replace('=','',base64_encode($bulan)).'&sl='.str_replace('=','',base64_encode($rs->fields['area_am_kode'])).'&sid='.$mLoad->mSID().'")><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></span></button></button>
                    </td>
                    <td>'.$rs->fields['area_am_kode'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$rs->fields['area_am_nama'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$rs->fields['area'].'</td>
                    <td colspan="5"><small>'.$rsc->fields['ins_group_produk'].'</small></td>
                  </tr>';
        }                                                       

        #Sales MR
        #Hitung Goal per MR dalam Persen
        $goal   = @($rs->fields['total_value']/$rs->fields['target_value'])*100;

        #Produk Group AM
        $rsd    = $m_db2->Execute("SELECT a.ins_group_produk FROM mst_insentive_pgroup AS a WHERE a.ins_kode='".$rs->fields['pg_mr']."'");                              

        echo '<tr>
                <td><button class="btn btn-sm btn-default" onclick=bukaWin("detail.mul?app=sales&mod=print_sales_mr&th='.str_replace('=','',base64_encode($tahun)).'&bl='.str_replace('=','',base64_encode($bulan)).'&sl='.str_replace('=','',base64_encode($rs->fields['mr_kode'])).'&sid='.$mLoad->mSID().'")><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></span></button></td>
                <td>'.$rs->fields['mr_kode'].'</td>
                <td>'.$rs->fields['mr_nama'].'</td>
                <td>'.$rsd->fields['ins_group_produk'].'</td>
                <td align="right">'.number_format($rs->fields['target_qty']).'</td>
                <td align="right">'.number_format($rs->fields['target_value']).'</td>
                <td align="right">'.number_format($rs->fields['total_qty']).'</td>
                <td align="right">'.number_format($rs->fields['total_value']).'</td>
                <td align="right">'.number_format(round($goal,2),2).' %</td>
              </tr>';

        #Hitung Sub Total
        #Subtotal Target
        $sub_tqty   += $rs->fields['target_qty'];
        $sub_tval   += $rs->fields['target_value'];

        #Subtotal Reals
        $sub_rqty   += $rs->fields['total_qty'];
        $sub_rval   += $rs->fields['total_value'];

        #Hitung Goal per AM dalam Persen
        $goal_am= @($sub_rval/$sub_tval)*100;

        #Hitung Goal Nasional
        $goal_nas= @($gran_rval/$gran_tval)*100;

        #Hitung Grand Total
        $gran_tqty  += $rs->fields['target_qty'];
        $gran_tval  += $rs->fields['target_value'];
        $gran_rqty  += $rs->fields['total_qty'];
        $gran_rval  += $rs->fields['total_value'];

        $rs->MoveNext();                                                                                    

        #Hitung Sub Total Group By AM
        if(@$cu_am!=$rs->fields['area_am_nama'])
        {
            $cu_am  = $rs->fields['area_am_nama'];

            echo '<tr>                                      
                    <td colspan="4"></td>
                    <td align="right" class="alert alert-danger">'.number_format($sub_tqty).'</td>
                    <td align="right" class="alert alert-danger">'.number_format($sub_tval).'</td>
                    <td align="right" class="alert alert-danger">'.number_format($sub_rqty).'</td>
                    <td align="right" class="alert alert-danger">'.number_format($sub_rval).'</td>
                    <td align="right" class="alert alert-danger">'.number_format(round($goal_am,2),2).' %</td>
                  </tr>';

            #Reset setiap kali group selanjutnya
            $goal_am    = 0;
            $sub_tqty   = 0;
            $sub_tval   = 0;
            $sub_rqty   = 0;
            $sub_rval   = 0;                                                                                            

        }                                                               

    }
    echo '<tr>
            <td colspan="8"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="tebal">                                       
            <td colspan="4" align="center"><b>Grand Total </b> # <i>'.ucwords(strtolower($rsb->fields['usr_nama'])).'</i></td>
            <td align="right" class="alert alert-warning"><b>'.number_format($gran_tqty).'</b></td>
            <td align="right" class="alert alert-warning"><b>'.number_format($gran_tval).'</b></td>
            <td align="right" class="alert alert-warning"><b>'.number_format($gran_rqty).'</b></td>
            <td align="right" class="alert alert-warning"><b>'.number_format($gran_rval).'</b></td>
            <td align="right" class="alert alert-warning"><b>'.number_format(round($goal_nas,2),2).' %</b></td>
          </tr>';
}else{
    echo '<tr>
            <td colspan="9" align="center">Pilih kriteria pencarian terlebih dahulu</td>
          </td>';
}
```

Comment: Thx @suraj for editing my question, sorry i'm newbie

Answer (score 0):

TRY: `SUM(IF(target_qty < 0, 0, target_qty)) as target_qty`

Comment: Thanks @dekts but failure no in SQL syntax i have no understand with my looping.